# Does TDataset call OnFilterRecord?

Tags: delphi, tdataset

The documentation on Delphi's TDataset.OnFilterRecord and TDataset.Filtered states:

> Occurs only when a record is fetched from a DB or when the Filtered property is set to True.
>   Write an OnFilterRecord event handler to specify for each record in a dataset whether it should be visible to the application. To indicate that a record passes the filter condition, the OnFilterRecord event handler must set the Accept parameter to true. To exclude a record, set the Accept parameter to false. Most TDataSet descendants (such as ADO datasets) initialize Accept to true before calling the OnFilterRecord event handler.
>
> Filtering is enabled if the Filtered property is true. When an application is processing a filter, the State property for the dataset is dsFilter.

It doesn't say that this functionality has to be implemented in TDataset descendants so I assumed that it works with every TDataset descendant. I tried it with Marco Cantu's [TMdDirDataset](http://www.marcocantu.com/code/md6htm/MdDataPack.htm#MdDsDir.pas) but it doesn't work.

Am I assuming wrong? Does TDataset only supply the properties but no implementation?

Comment: It is as you say. Descendants must implement triggering of the `OnFilterRecord` event by themselves, `TDataset` does not fire this event anywhere.

Comment: Filtering is only allowed on uni-directional datasets (those that can scroll in both directions), so it would have to be implemented in descendants. You can check Marco's source to find out if it was or not.